# HTML form -> Flash submit button -> Set a PHP variable in flash button -> Submit form

Tags: php, javascript, flash, actionscript-3, forms

Okay, I'm sorry that this is pretty complicated, but it shouldn't be that hard to solve...

Here's what I want to do. I have an HTML form that I want to upload to MySQL with PHP. That part's easy, but the thing is I want the submit button to be a Flash object. Somehow I need the Flash button to submit the form, but I think I can figure that out. The tricky part is that I need it to set another PHP variable before submitting the form. The variable will be determined by a bunch of stuff, but I can code that in actionscript later. I just need to figure out how to pass the variable back to the webpage. A $_POST variable would probably be fine.

Thanks!! Let me know if I need to clarify more...

edit: What if the flash object returned some javascript and set a variable that way?
Can anyone help with making it submit the form as well while still catching a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?allClasses=1) for calling JavaScript from ActionScript and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Lars is right about it. It may look like this

ExternalInterface.call('passmyvariables','value1','value2');

Your javasscript would be something like this

function passmyvariables(var1,var2){

//process myvar

form.submit();

}

you can have multiple variables.

Comment: Interesting... I will look into this too

Answer (score 0):

1. An accessibility tip: avoid Flash when possible; it causes usability issues.
2. If you want to add a POST variable before submitting:

   2. I don't think that Flash is allowed to access the DOM so this is JavaScript:
   3. Create an `input` element appended as a child of the `form`
   4. Set its `type` to `hidden`
   5. Set its `value` to whatever you want to send.

That's only *part* of the equation; I don't know how to get Flash to trigger a script in the page.

**EDIT**

These functions can help get data from Flash objects.

`flashObject.GetVariable(variableName)`

`flashObject.SetVariable(variableName, value)`

Comment: 1. Yeah, I know... It's kind of a limited appeal application. Haha
2. Hmm.. That doesn't really help, I need flash to set the variable. It's gonna be determined by an interactive thing. Maybe flash could return a line of javascript though?

Comment: Interesting... You'll have to excuse the fact that I'm a javascript and actionscript noob, but... I'm assuming if the flash object can pass a variable, those functions can grab the value without having to refresh the page or anything?

Comment: Exactly. JavaScript can grab/set Flash vars with these funcs.

Comment: That sounds very handy, I'll look into these. Thanks